# Specific Fields for Specific User types in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, model, database-normalization

I'm trying to come up with a better structure for handling user data in a django app. Currently, There are two kinds of users in the app, individual and organization. There is data specific to an individual and data specific to an organization. For example, an individual can have a first and last name while a organization only has their organization name.

This is how the model currently looks

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True) # from AbstractUser
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True) # from AbstractUser
    organization_name = models.CharField(_('organization name'), max_length=180, blank=True)
    is_individual = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_organization = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Is there a way specific fields can be set up for specific user types? Something like:

```
Individual
-- first_name
-- last_name
# more data concerning individuals

Organization
-- organization_name
# more data concerning organizations
```

Comment: Can organizations login to the system?

Comment: yes, organizations can login to the system

Comment: Rearrangement for subtyping is not DB normalization. Also it's a faq.

Answer (score 2):

Use One to One Fields to map Organization and Individual users to the actual User model.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    is_individual = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_organization = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    organization_name = models.CharField(_('organization name'), max_length=180, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )

class IndividualUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True) # from AbstractUser
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True) # from AbstractUser
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create 2 different classes for Individual and Organization

```py
class User(Abstract):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True) # from AbstractUser
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True) # from AbstractUser
   

class Organization(Abstract):
    organization_name = models.CharField(_('organization name'), max_length=180, blank=True)
```

in `view.py` by checking condition `is_individual` / `is_organization` you can store and retrieve that details in respective table in database.

Comment: Thanks. would work but i want to use a single model to handle all the authentication. Creating two user classes means that authentication will be split between two models.